# Save a Video that I record in my app

Tags: ios, video, sdk, camera

I am succeeding in understanding how to make a camera app in my learning journey:-)

The only thing I am stuck with is saving a video that I have recorded. I am able to save a photo, but the same does not work for videos.

So I think I have almost got it with the help of iBrad Apps.

got this code:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
 {
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    UIImage *image = [info 
                      objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    imageView.image = image;

    if (newMedia)
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, 
                                       self,
                                       @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                       nil);
}
else{

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
        UIImage *movie = [info 
                          objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh];

        videoRecorder2.image = movie;

            if (newMedia)
                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(movie, 
                                               self,
                                               @selector(movie:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                               nil);
}}}
```

I have an if statement because the app can take both video and still images.

The first part is for still - which works and then the second part I am still tutu-ing with:-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(moviepath,nil,nil,nil);
```

Edit: Try this and modify your code to this method:

```
// For responding to the user tapping Cancel.
- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel: (UIImagePickerController *) picker {

    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    [picker release];
}

// For responding to the user accepting a newly-captured picture or movie
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
            didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    UIImage *originalImage, *editedImage, *imageToSave;

    // Handle a still image capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0)
            == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

        editedImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                    UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                    UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        if (editedImage) {
            imageToSave = editedImage;
        } else {
            imageToSave = originalImage;
        }

    // Save the new image (original or edited) to the Camera Roll
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (imageToSave, nil, nil , nil);
    }

    // Handle a movie capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
            == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

        NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:
                    UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];

        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (
                    moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
        }
    }

    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

Comment: Sounds like I the right way - I have added some code to show what I am doing - cheers

Comment: Check if movie is nil or if newMedia is nil.

Comment: Sorry is that a question or the answer? newMedia is a Boolean and so I am thinking that it should be nil - so that it can save the clip right? maybe I am on the wrong trail here.

Comment: Check that both of those objects exist then I we will work from there.

Comment: IBOutlet UIImageView *videoRecorder2;
 BOOL newMedia;

There they are in my .h file - they come up the green-ish color so it is recognizing them.

Comment: use an NSLog and check if they exist.

Comment: ok - mmmm maybe bad code practice, but I have never used NSLog before. sorry:-(

Comment: try removing this line: videoRecorder2.image = movie;

Comment: I am getting this warning: Incompatible pointer types passing 'UIImage *' to parameter of type 'NSString *'

Comment: ok cool :-) It seems to work, I still got a few bugs, but i'll learn and work through them - thanks iBrad:-)

Comment: no problem! Yea your main issue before was that you were setting a Image to a Video. haha :)

Comment: ok - yeah that makes sense, when I tried your code it would not dismiss the view though, neither images or video - so I combined my initial code and after the else entered your video part of the solution and it works after that. I'll do some more staring at the screen and see if I can make it work cleaner:-)

Comment: Thanks!
How can I later load up this video from the saved place to the GUI?

Comment: Sorry for the really late response. Just use MPMoviePlayerController and do it that way since it is the easiest way. :P